# Choosing when to use a friend function

Tags: c++, friend

Refer [C++ FAQ lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/member-vs-friend-fns.html)

It states for binary infix arithmetic operators :

```
member functions don't allow promotion of the left hand argument, since that 
would change the class of the object that is the recipient of the member 
function invocation
```

Can someone please explain why this is so ? Why is there a constrain on the type of first argument ?

Thank you.

Comment: Talk about pulling something out of context!!

Comment: @KerrekSB is the question flawed ?

Comment: Well, it might have been nice to say a bit more clearly that you're talking about overloading operators, or provide a more complete and self-contained quote...

Comment: Prefer, in order: 1) non-friend free functions 2) friend free functions 3) member functions. Between 2 and 3, do 3 unless you need the abilities given by 2. The FAQ misses the point about preferring 1, which is important.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider this:

```
struct Number {
    Number(int val) : val(val) {  }    // *Not* explicit
    int val;                           // Everything public to simplify example

    Number operator+(Number const& other) const { return val + other.val; }
};

Number n(42);
Number result = 32 + n;    // Doesn't compile
```

But if we removed the member operator and made it a free function instead:

```
Number operator+(Number const& a, Number const& b) { return a.val + b.val; }

Number n(42);
Number result = 32 + n;    // Compiles!
```

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have a type `Foo` so that for `Foo f; int n;` both of the expressions `f + n` and `n + f` make sense.

By overloading the member `operator+`, you can only ever implement `f + n`:

```
struct Foo
{
    Bar operator+(int n) const;       // binds to "Foo + int"
    // ...
};
```

You can never get the other version, `int + Foo`, from a member operator. The solution is to define the *free* operator, which can be made for any signature that involves at least one user-defined type. In fact, we can recycle the member operator like so:

```
Bar operator+(int n, Foo const & f)   // binds to "int + Foo"
{
    return f + n;                     // recycle existing implementation
}
```

When you *only* have a free operator overload, it often makes sense to make it a `friend` of `Foo` so that it can access the interna of that class. In our case we didn't need this because we just pass the call on to the member operator.

Comment: @Cameron: Thanks, though your example also touches on a nice point about implicit conversions.